# Exception in Visual Studio.Net: System.OutofMemory.Exception

Tags: visual-studio, exception, c#-4.0

I am working with VisualStudio 2010 and this would probably be the most common error.
In my code I am calling a script to load data from a database table which comprises of over 1,765,700 rows and is 777,826 KB size.

I keep running into an System.OutOfMemory.Exception error.

Is there anyway I can increase the memory being allocated to my program or change the settings? I had done it while running my programs in eclipse before. Can it be done in Visual Studio2010 as well?

Thank you

Comment: The amount of memory available to a C# program (or any other kind of program) is the same on any 32-bit operating system, 2 gigabytes, the maximum available.  This is unlike Java (Eclipse) where you have to tell the JVM how much memory it can use.  Reading the entire data table into an array or List<> can certainly bomb your program.  You have to write smarter code or use a 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be, if at all possible, to not load all of the data into memory at once unless this is truly a requirement.  If there is any way to load the data in stages, you would avoid coming close to the memory limitations.

However, changing this to target x64 and running on a 64bit platform should give you plenty of memory access to load this amount of data without issues.  That would potentially be the simplest option.

Comment: I am running it on a 32 bit os. It is proving to be a real pain :(

Comment: @jill Then you should consider *streaming* the results instead of loading them all into memory.  What are you doing that requires loading all of this data in memory, at once?

Comment: How do I stream the results? As of now I am using the Datatable.load() method to load each resultset. So every data table is read and loaded into memory. My understanding is that when I do this - one datatable is read & loaded then the memory is set free to load the next table. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @jill Yes, but make sure that you aren't keeping references to old data around.  Alternatively (and potentially better), use DataReader to read the data in chunks instead of all at once: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=VS.100).aspx